# Attempting to stop wav file from playing on second JButton Press

Tags: java, audio, wav

It can locate the .wav file, however it will not play the file when the JButton is pressed.  i recently asked a similar question here about this same code and how it wouldn't stop on the second JButton press, but instead would create a new instance of the audio.  A kind person suggested I change my variables to instance fields, something I have very little experience in doing.  I tried to change them, but I most likely did it wrong.  Here is my Code:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import java.lang.NullPointerException;

import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;

import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;

import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class aMeme extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

  public JButton button;

  public boolean check;

  public boolean audio;

  public static URL fg;

  public static AudioInputStream gram;

  public static Clip fitness;

  static{

    try{

      URL fg = new URL ("file:c:/Users/kebrobst18/Downloads/test.wav");

      Clip fitness = AudioSystem.getClip();

      AudioInputStream gram = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fg);

    }

    catch (LineUnavailableException f){

    }

    catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException f) {

    }

  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){

    if (check == true){

      BufferedImage img = null;

      try{

        img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/kebrobst18/Downloads/Fitnessgram.png"));

      }

      catch (IOException e){

      }

      g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);

     }

  }

  public void start(){

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    button=new JButton();

    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

    button.setText("Start/Stop"); 

    button.addActionListener(this);

    add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setSize(500,500);

    setVisible(true);

    audio = false;

  }       

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){    

    check = true;

    repaint();

    try{

      if (audio == false){

        fitness.open();

        fitness.start();

      }      

      else if (audio == true){

        fitness.stop();

        audio = false;

     }

    }

    catch (LineUnavailableException f){

    }

    catch(IllegalArgumentException f){

    }

    catch(NullPointerException f){

    }

  } 

  public static void main(String args[]){

    aMeme x = new aMeme();

    x.start();

  }

}
```

Comment: when do you ever set `audio = true`?

Comment: I'm sure you don't write code on every other line, so don't post code formatted like that. It you want us to read code then make the code readable. Class names start with upper case characters. All you need to do is look at the Java API to see this Java convention. Don't use static variables. Don't override paint(), especially on a frame. There is no need for "repInt()" in the ActionLIstener. You were given simple working code in your last question. All you need to do is start/stop the clip based on a variable indicating the current state of the clip.

Comment: You've ignored nearly all of the advice that Hovercraft Full Of Eels gave you on your last question. His points about exceptions are especially important. Exceptions tell you when there is an error, what type of error and generally have a useful message about why it occurred. By ignoring all exceptions, if there is a problem with the Clip or the file, you will never find out about it and we would not be able to help you. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/ I personally just won't help people if they have empty catch blocks. It's like driving without watching the road.